# The boundary of certain sets in the domain of a smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that $u(x)$ is a sufficiently smooth function on some domain $D \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ and $ s $‌ is  a fixed real value. The goal is to find the boundary of the  set $ E= \{x\in D : u(x) > s\}$.

My guess is $ \partial E = \{x\in D: u(x) =s \}$ but I fail to show this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly true, consider $u(x)=-\|x\|^2$ and $s=0$ on any $D$ containing a neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the most you can say here in general is $$D\cap\partial E\subset\{u=s\}.$$

This can be a proper inclusion, if $u$ has a local maximum at a point where $u=s$. The argument zhw gave shows that if $\nabla u$ never vanishes then $$D\cap\partial E=\{u=s\}.$$

But in general $\partial E$ can also contain points of $\partial D$; if you want to say $\partial E=\{u=s\}$ you need another hypothesis to rule that out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a natural condition for equality of the two sets. Suppose $u:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is smooth and $\nabla u$ vanishes nowhere. Then for every $s,$ $\partial \{u>s\} = \{u=s\}.$

Proof: That the left side is a subset of the right is easy. Suppose $u(a) = s.$ Define $f(t) = u(a+t\nabla u(a)).$ Then $f'(0) = |\nabla u(a)|^2>0.$ Thus $f(t)> f(0) =u(a)$ for small positive $t.$ This implies $a,$ being the limit of points in $\{u>s\},$ is in $\partial \{u>s\}.$

Comment: You need more hypotheses - if $u>1$ everywhere and $s=0$ then the left side is not a subset of the right side.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm in $\mathbb R^n$ and the boundary of $\mathbb R^n$ is the empty set.

Comment: I missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary of $E$ is a subset of the set that you mentioned, but they don't have to be equal, no matter how nice $u$ is. Take, for instance $u\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $u(x)=x^3-3x$ and take $s=2$. Then $E=(2,+\infty)$ and therefore $\partial E=\{2\}$. But$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,u(x)=2\}=\{-1,2\}.$$

Comment: I'm confused by this - I suspect that what you're calling $D$ is what the OP called $E$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the reply. Is there any condition under which $\partial E $ actually equals the set I mentioned?

Comment: @Erfan Right now, I can't think of any such condition.

Comment: Great, now I underrstand what you're saying. What you say is not quite true;  $\partial E$ can also intersect $\partial D$.